# Where in the google workspace admin console is the option to get a pin so as to call them

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I used to use "google apps for business" which was then called G Suite and then called Google workspace.. so currently called google workspace.. I subscribe and cancel from time to time just using it periodically.

Currently I want to use it and I have in the past used the option to call Google but I can't see the option..

[image]

I found some numbers listed that I think are from Google e.g. 00 1 877 355 5787 and 00 1 646 257 4500  that are mentioned at 0:53 of this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bi9J5SqQ-8&ab_channel=MikeMurphyCo

[image]

And I even found a link here https://www.goldyarora.com/g-suite-customer-service-numbers-country-wise/  that has a bunch of numbers, I checked those ones and they are listed. So looks maybe legit.. And the numbers say the same thing, to go to  workspace.google.com/pin (so definitely not a scam).  That link redirects to https://support.google.com/a/answer/60233  I can't see a phone number though. Judging by here, i'm not sure if it's only available on a particular level of subscription, of "enhanced support"? https://workspace.google.com/support/?referral-tabs_activeEl=enhanced-support

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. Remember that you might accept your answer, and if you get another answer, you might accept the other answer if you like that one more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Go to https://support.google.com/a. If your Google Workspace admin account is not active, activate it.

[image]

As of the end of September 2023, near the bottom, there is a Contact Us button that takes you to a page with the support options about Google Workspace Admin. For users signed in with a Google Workspace admin account, it will show the step-by-step instructions to contact a specialist, **including** a "Go there now" button.

---

The problem with user-created content on platforms like YouTube is that this content might become obsolete, and there is no standard way to identify that.

The most direct option is to go to https://admin.google.com. The problem is that Google likes to update the user interface from time to time. This might not be very clear for admins who do not have to access this app frequently, and if they do this in a hurry, looking to contact support quickly might be a big problem entering the app after a long time and finding an unfamiliar user interface showing unexpected pop-ups.

Remember that most Google product help centers are hosted at https://support.google.com in cases like the above. The help center for Google Workspace Admin is not the exception. The direct URL is **https://support.google.com/a**.

Tip: Sign in using your Google Workspace account as the primary account. If you have signed in using multiple accounts, double-check that the user profile photo shows the photo of your Google Workspace admin account. This is relevant because the Google Workspace Admin Help Center is customized based on the user account. It might immediately show the contact support options when it detects that the user account is a Google Workspace account. *Your mileage might vary*. In any case, it has a big search box on top. Search is what built the house's name. Anyway, the Help Center usually keeps a simple and clean design. Compared with what is sometimes shown to Google Workspace Admins, it might be less stressful and easier to navigate / search, in this case, to find the information necessary to contact support.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about calling them , but a bit of a workaround, there is a chat option, that is to a live person and is or can be helpful.

if you click the question mark icon

[image]

It is mentioned here "Contact Google Workspace support" https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en

You have to have a Workspace account to do it and to log into it, you don't use the email address you used to create it. You use a username that is a username/"email address" they email you which is blah@domain  where domain is the domain you told them.

Then you are logged in as admin to google workspace, and it will show the question mark, and so you can then click the question mark and from there, get to the chat.

Comment: It should not only be a Google Workspace account, but it should also be one with admin privileges. I mention this because I have seen cases where people forgot that they have to switch to the admin account when having one for normal work and another for admin tasks.

Comment: My answer takes to the same place, it suggests starting from the help center because of Google's habit of changing the UX.